# React routing link from nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested, react-router-dom

I want to add routing to my app but the "Link" I made in a child component doesn't work onClick, but only when I refresh the page. I guess the problem is the way too much nesting but I have no idea how can I solve it.

One mention: I imported BrowserRouter as Router everywhere.

[This is the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1umj8.png)

This is the code spippets that related to my problem:

App component:

```
   function App() {
  return (
    <Router >
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={NewFetch} />
          <Route path="/cardID/:id" component={Details} />     //The route that doesn't work
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

NewFetch (Main) component:

```
<Router> //Tried with <React.Fragment>
...
   <Route path={["/cards/:name", "/cards/:filter"]}>
      <Filter isLoaded={isLoaded} handleScroll={handleScroll} toScrollTop={toScrollTop} value={value} 
         scrollPosition={scrollPosition} jumpToTop={jumpToTop} testFilter={testFilter} />
   </Route>
</Router>
```

Card (child 2) component from :

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.img ? "card" : "hide"}>
      <Link to={`/cardID/id=${props.id}`} >          //Link that doesn't connect
        <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} />
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
};
```

So basically I can't connect the "Link" from a hardly nested component.

Comment: With the middle code snippet what were you trying to achieve there and you can **not** give a path as an array

Comment: Basically i wanna load 2 different api calls to the same component, and i wanted to separate the urls for them

Comment: If  you want to make two request or more to a back-end api you have to make use of ```axios.all``` seems like you have more than one query here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router >
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={NewFetch} />
          <Route path="/cardID/:id" component={Details} />     //The route that doesn't work
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router
```

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.img ? "card" : "hide"}>
      <Link to={`/cardID/id=${props.id}`} >          //Link that doesn't connect
        <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} />
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
};
```

**Above is your code which might look right but the is a slight bug here:**

- The bug is in the wrong way you are linking to `path="/cardID/:id`
- What you are to do is in your **Card child2** is:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.img ? "card" : "hide"}>
      <Link to={`/cardID/${props.id}`} > //Removed **id=....**
        <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} />
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
};
```

- This is what you have to understand that when you make a route like so `path="/route/:id"` the **:id** is just a placeholder waiting for you to place anything so **id** is commonly used so your code makes sense and mainly basically you want to route based on id but one could have written **:cat** for example but that is just a placeholder

Comment: It might be surprising but it doesn't work even though it should. I rewrote the code but i got the same "effect".

Comment: I did and you were right about this, but after a bit more research I figured out that I had 1 more Router tag in my child component, that's why my Link does't triggered.